# Can't make the progressbar display normally via MediaControl

Tags: android, kotlin, view, android-mediaplayer, android-mediasession

I've made a music player with Media player. I want to make the media notification appear inside my control center so I've used mediasession to achieve it. However, despite everything else looks like normal, but I can't get the progress bar's handle appear.

Here is the service I used to handle music player:

```
package org.akanework.symphonica.logic.service

import android.app.Notification
import android.app.Service
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
import android.media.MediaMetadata
import android.media.MediaPlayer
import android.media.session.MediaSession
import android.media.session.PlaybackState
import android.os.IBinder
import android.util.Log
import androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources
import androidx.core.graphics.drawable.toBitmap
import androidx.core.net.toUri
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DiskCacheStrategy
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions
import com.bumptech.glide.request.target.CustomTarget
import com.bumptech.glide.request.transition.Transition
import org.akanework.symphonica.MainActivity
import org.akanework.symphonica.MainActivity.Companion.actuallyPlaying
import org.akanework.symphonica.MainActivity.Companion.isLoopEnabled
import org.akanework.symphonica.MainActivity.Companion.isShuffleEnabled
import org.akanework.symphonica.MainActivity.Companion.musicPlayer
import org.akanework.symphonica.MainActivity.Companion.playlistViewModel
import org.akanework.symphonica.MainActivity.Companion.updateAlbumView
import org.akanework.symphonica.R
import org.akanework.symphonica.SymphonicaApplication.Companion.context
import org.akanework.symphonica.logic.util.changePlayer
import org.akanework.symphonica.logic.util.nextSong
import org.akanework.symphonica.logic.util.prevSong
import kotlin.random.Random

class SymphonicaPlayerService : Service(), MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {

    /*


     */

    companion object {
        fun updatePlaybackState() {
            musicPlayer?.let {
                val playbackStateBuilder = PlaybackState.Builder()
                    .setActions(PlaybackState.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE or PlaybackState.ACTION_SKIP_TO_NEXT or PlaybackState.ACTION_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS)

                if (actuallyPlaying) {
                    playbackStateBuilder.setState(
                        PlaybackState.STATE_PLAYING,
                        it.currentPosition.toLong(),
                        1.0f
                    )
                } else {
                    playbackStateBuilder.setState(
                        PlaybackState.STATE_PAUSED,
                        it.currentPosition.toLong(),
                        0.0f
                    )
                }

                mediaSession.setPlaybackState(playbackStateBuilder.build())
            }
            updateAlbumView()
        }

        val mediaSession = MediaSession(context, "PlayerService")
        val mediaStyle = Notification.MediaStyle().setMediaSession(mediaSession.sessionToken)
        val notification = Notification.Builder(context, "channel_symphonica")
            .setStyle(mediaStyle)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_note)
            .setActions()
            .build()


        fun updateMetadata() {
            /*
            if (playlistViewModel.playList[playlistViewModel.currentLocation].cover != null) {
                mediaSession.setMetadata(
                    MediaMetadata.Builder()
                        .putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, playlistViewModel.playList[playlistViewModel.currentLocation].title)
                        .putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, playlistViewModel.playList[playlistViewModel.currentLocation].artist)
                        .putBitmap(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART, playlistViewModel.playList[playlistViewModel.currentLocation].cover!!.toBitmap())
                        .putLong(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_DURATION, playlistViewModel.playList[playlistViewModel.currentLocation].duration)
                        .build()
                )
            } else {

             */
            var initialized = false
            lateinit var bitmapResource: Bitmap
            Glide.with(context)
                 .asBitmap()
                 .load(playlistViewModel.playList[playlistViewModel.currentLocation].imgUri)
                 .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_album_default_cover)
                 .into(object : CustomTarget<Bitmap>(){
                    override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
                        bitmapResource = resource
                        initialized = true
                        mediaSession.setMetadata(
                            MediaMetadata.Builder()
                                .putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, playlistViewModel.playList[playlistViewModel.currentLocation].title)
                                .putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, playlistViewModel.playList[playlistViewModel.currentLocation].artist)
                                .putBitmap(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART, bitmapResource)
                                .putLong(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_DURATION, playlistViewModel.playList[playlistViewModel.currentLocation].duration)
                                .build()
                        )
                    }
                    override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {
                        // this is called when imageView is cleared on lifecycle call or for
                        // some other reason.
                        // if you are referencing the bitmap somewhere else too other than this imageView
                        // clear it here as you can no longer have the bitmap
                    }
                })
            // }
            if (initialized == false) {
                mediaSession.setMetadata(
                    MediaMetadata.Builder()
                        .putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, playlistViewModel.playList[playlistViewModel.currentLocation].title)
                        .putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, playlistViewModel.playList[playlistViewModel.currentLocation].artist)
                        .putBitmap(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART, AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_album_default_cover)!!.toBitmap())
                        .putLong(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_DURATION, playlistViewModel.playList[playlistViewModel.currentLocation].duration)
                        .build()
                )
            }
            MainActivity.managerSymphonica.notify(1, notification)
        }
    }

    private val mediaSessionCallback = object : MediaSession.Callback() {
        override fun onSeekTo(pos: Long) {
            musicPlayer?.seekTo(pos.toInt())
            updatePlaybackState()
        }

        override fun onSkipToNext() {
            nextSong()
        }

        override fun onSkipToPrevious() {
            prevSong()
        }

        override fun onPause() {
            changePlayer()
            updatePlaybackState()
        }

        override fun onPlay() {
            changePlayer()
            updatePlaybackState()
        }
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }


    override fun onPrepared(mp: MediaPlayer) {
        mp.start()
        mediaSession.setActive(true)
        mediaSession.setCallback(mediaSessionCallback)
        updateMetadata()
        updatePlaybackState()
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        when(intent.action) {
            "ACTION_REPLACE_AND_PLAY" -> {
                if (musicPlayer == null) {
                    musicPlayer = MediaPlayer()
                    setLoopListener()
                    startPlaying()

                } else {
                    stopAndPlay()
                }
            }
            "ACTION_PAUSE" -> {
                if (musicPlayer != null && musicPlayer!!.isPlaying) {
                    musicPlayer!!.pause()
                }
            }
            "ACTION_RESUME" -> {
                if (musicPlayer != null && !musicPlayer!!.isPlaying) {
                    musicPlayer!!.start()
                }
            }
            "ACTION_NEXT" -> {
                if (musicPlayer != null) {
                    musicPlayer!!.reset()
                    nextSongDecisionMaker()
                    if (actuallyPlaying) {
                        startPlaying()
                    }
                }
            }
            "ACTION_PREV" -> {
                if (musicPlayer != null) {
                    musicPlayer!!.reset()
                    prevSongDecisionMaker()
                    startPlaying()
                }
            }
            "ACTION_JUMP" -> {
                if (musicPlayer != null) {
                    stopAndPlay()
                } else {
                    musicPlayer = MediaPlayer()
                    setLoopListener()
                    startPlaying()
                }
            }
        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
    }

    private fun startPlaying() {
        musicPlayer!!.apply {
            setDataSource(applicationContext, playlistViewModel.playList[
                playlistViewModel.currentLocation
            ].path.toUri())
            setOnPreparedListener(this@SymphonicaPlayerService)
            prepareAsync()
            broadcastPlayStart()
            setLoopListener()
        }
    }

    private fun stopAndPlay() {
        musicPlayer!!.reset()
        startPlaying()
    }

    private fun setLoopListener() {
        musicPlayer!!.setOnCompletionListener {
            nextSongDecisionMaker()
            if (musicPlayer != null) {
                musicPlayer!!.reset()
                musicPlayer!!.apply {
                    setDataSource(applicationContext, playlistViewModel.playList[
                        playlistViewModel.currentLocation
                    ].path.toUri())
                    setOnPreparedListener(this@SymphonicaPlayerService)
                    prepareAsync()
                    broadcastPlayStart()
                    setLoopListener()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun stopPlaying() {
        musicPlayer!!.reset()
        musicPlayer!!.release()
        musicPlayer = null
    }

    private fun broadcastPlayStart() {
        val intent = Intent("org.akanework.symphonica.PLAY_START")
        sendBroadcast(intent)
        if (MainActivity.managerSymphonica.activeNotifications.isEmpty()) {
            mediaSession.setCallback(mediaSessionCallback)
        }
    }

    private fun prevSongDecisionMaker() {
        playlistViewModel.currentLocation =
        if (playlistViewModel.currentLocation == 0 && isLoopEnabled && !isShuffleEnabled) {
            playlistViewModel.playList.size - 1
        } else if (playlistViewModel.currentLocation == 0 && !isLoopEnabled && !isShuffleEnabled) {
            stopPlaying()
            actuallyPlaying = false
            0
        } else if (playlistViewModel.currentLocation != 0 && !isShuffleEnabled) {
            playlistViewModel.currentLocation - 1
        } else if (isShuffleEnabled && playlistViewModel.playList.size != 1) {
            Random.nextInt(0, playlistViewModel.playList.size - 1)
        } else {
            0
        }
    }

    private fun nextSongDecisionMaker() {
        playlistViewModel.currentLocation =
            if (playlistViewModel.currentLocation == playlistViewModel.playList.size - 1 && isLoopEnabled && !isShuffleEnabled) {
                0
            } else if (playlistViewModel.currentLocation == playlistViewModel.playList.size - 1 && !isLoopEnabled && !isShuffleEnabled) {
                stopPlaying()
                actuallyPlaying = false
                0
            } else if (playlistViewModel.currentLocation != playlistViewModel.playList.size - 1 && !isShuffleEnabled) {
                playlistViewModel.currentLocation + 1
            } else if (isShuffleEnabled && playlistViewModel.playList.size != 1) {
                Random.nextInt(0, playlistViewModel.playList.size - 1)
            } else {
                0
            }
    }

}
```

Here is part of the code inside MainActivity that I've used to deal with the notification.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        managerSymphonica = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        channelSymphonica = NotificationChannel("channel_symphonica", "Symphonica", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
        managerSymphonica.createNotificationChannel(channelSymphonica)
}
```

I've tried to rewrite the service but nothing happens. There isn't much inside official documentation.kotli